# Jersey client Post Request with x-www-form-urlencoded Fails

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

Hi I am using Glassfish jersey-client to get oauth-Token from REST URL.
I am able to get the token via postman client & CURL,please find the below image for reference,

```
$ curl 'https://sample.com/oauth2/token' -X POST -d'g
rant_type=samples&id=2ZwqWBdksfjkads6Q8yNW3s58LNeOMucJeb&s                                                                                                                
ecret=dkfflJTZOqA1GCEH&scope=GROUP'
```

But unable to achieve it via code,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am using following code to get the token

```
Form form = new Form();
        form.param("grant_type", "samples");
        form.param("id", "2ZwqWBdksfjkads6Q8yNW3s58LNeOMucJeb");
        form.param("secret", "HGoslJTZOqA1GCEH");
        form.param("scope", "dkfflJTZOqA1GCEH");
JerseyClientBuilder jerseyClientBuilder = new JerseyClientBuilder()
            .register(new LoggingFilter());
    JerseyWebTarget jerseyWebTarget =      jerseyClientBuilder.build().target(hostname);
        response = jerseyWebTarget.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(Entity.form(form));
```

Keep on getting StatusCode=406(Not acceptable) as a response.
Shall i passing the URL parameters properly?

I would highly appreciate if someone give me a hint to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Get rid of this `.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)`. This sets the `Accept` header. You are saying here that you want a response  with data type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The server doesn't know how to response with that type so it's telling you that that response type is not acceptable.

What you want is to send the `Content-Type` header, not the `Accept` header. Using `Entity.form(Form)` automatically sets the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so you really don't need to do anything else. Just remove the `accept` method call.

---

#### UPDATE

Seems the client is setting an Accept header the server doesn't like, so you can explicitly set the `Accept` header to `application/json` since that is the content-type sent back by the server for the token response.

If you want to get the token as a Java object, you can just create a `Token` class with all the JSON properties in the token

```
public class Token {
    @JsonProperty("access_token")
    private String accessToken;

    // other properties

    public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return this.accessToken;
    }

    // other getters and setters
}
```

Then just do

```
Token token = response.readEntity(Token.class);
```

If you don't know all the other properties in the token response, just look at the contents of the logging filter. You should see the response. But you need to configure the logging filter to show the body

```
.register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true));
```

Comment: Removed accept header but keep on getting the same error "406-Not acceptable"

Comment: Sorry i am not getting you. You asked me to remove.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) and then try. I tried it but it is not working.

Comment: Basically I am saying "ok well that's all I got for you. Setting the accept headers to form-urlencoded would cause the error. I don't what else it could possibly be"

Comment: You an try to explicitly set the accept header to `application/json`, though I am not sure if that will help or not

Comment: It is working now after setting the following accept header "accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)" works like a charm.Now i am getting status code as "OK" how shall we see the response body.It should return oauth token.Where shall i see the token in the response.